# Python 2.7 - String Substitution using multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, string, dictionary, substitution

I am mostly self taught, so I'm having a hard time looking up the answer - I think because I don't know what it's called.

Basically I need to use the `"%(dict_key)s" %(dict)` syntax but using multiple dictionaries. I have no idea how to do this. A quick rough example would be:

```
dict1 = {"foo": "bar"}
dict2 = {"car": "vroom"}

print "Value 1 is %(foo)s and value 2 is %(car)s" %(dict1, dict2)
```

That example doesn't work, obviously, but that's what I need. How do I do this? I'm looking for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict(dict1, **dict2)`:

```
>>> dict1 = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> dict2 = {"car": "vroom"}

>>> dict(dict1, **dict2)
{'car': 'vroom', 'foo': 'bar'}

>>> print "Value 1 is %(foo)s and value 2 is %(car)s" % dict(dict1, **dict2)
Value 1 is bar and value 2 is vroom
```